# file_managed vs files tables

Tags: files

I am attempting to add a file to a node.  I am using the following code which is saving the file to the file_managed table in Drupal without issue:

```
//query old DB for the pieces of the file I need happens above this

foreach($result as $r) {
  echo "Processing nid: " . $r->nid . "\r\n";

  //update nodes with the thumbnails
  if ($node = node_load($r->nid)) { //make sure there is a node to load
    $file_temp = file_get_contents('http://www.example.org/' . str_replace(' ', '%20', $r->filepath));
    $file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, 'public://' . str_replace(' ', '_', $r->filename), FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    $node->field_thumbail['und'][0] = array (
      'uid' => 1,
      'fid' => $file_temp->fid,
      'uri' => $file_temp->filename,
      'filemime' => $file_temp->filemime,
      'status' => 1,
      'display' => 1,
    );
    print_r($file_temp);
    node_save($node);
  }
}
```

That saves the file just fine, and appears to save node with the correct information too.  However, Drupal renders it like this:

[image: View of the file field in edit view]

The file exists at the URL, and entering the file URL in the browser renders the file.  There is an entry in the {file_managed} table and the data is saved to the node.  That is, if I do a:

```
drush php-eval 'print_r(node_load($nid))'
```

replacing $nid with my node id, the field_thumbnail looks to be properly populated.

There is not, however, an entry in the files table for this fid.

I'm wondering what the difference between files_managed and files tables are?  Do I need to also save it to the files table for Drupal to render it properly?

Comment: Drupal 7 doesn't have a `files` table...maybe it's a remnant from a D6 install?

Comment: That would make sense, this is an upgrade from a D6 site.  Any thoughts on why the files wouldn't be rendering?  They are in the file_managed table, and exist on the server at the correct path.  Thanks